# SSE Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 with a server that provides Server Sent Events (SSE)

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

I am trying to connect browsers with a server that provides Server Sent Events (SSE). This server has a different domain than the original one. For example if you call `http://d1.example.com/page` this page will try to connect to an SSE channel on `http://d2.example.com/subscribe`. Trying to do that will prompt the following error:

`Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18`

on the line:

`var source = new EventSource("http://d2.example.com/subscribe")`

How can I fix that?

**Update (Solutions that I have tried out):**

1- CORS

I tried [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to the headers of my web service `d2.example.com`. It did not solve `EventSource` problem, even though `$.get("http://d2.example.com")` calls from `d1.example.com` pages are working fine now! I thought SSE works on normal HTTP requests, so why is it not working on Chrome?

2- Redirect

I am using httpd server, so I created a redirect rule in `d1.example.com` virtual host that passes SSE requests to `d2.example.com`. It worked perfectly with Firefox. Chrome on the other hand did not prompt any error and did not connect to the SSE server either. It looks like it dumped the whole `EventSource` command. It looks like this solution will never work, so lets move on...

3- Reverse proxy

Both browsers connected on `d1.example.com/subscribe` which is basically connecting to `d2.example.com` through reverse proxy. But `on_close` event is never caught, even if the browser is closed. Which makes sense since the d2 server is now making the channel with the proxy server. How can I forward the `on_close` event from proxy server to d2?

Is there any different ways that could make this work?

Comment: @Jack It is not the same question. This question does not require a file. A file is quite easy you could make a redirect rule as a worst case scenario or a reverse proxy. SSE will not work by those solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The odds are high this is an issue of cross-origin resource sharing, which you must enable on the relevant domains.

http://enable-cors.org/

As the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) says:

> Note: Although it's not yet part of the standard, EventSource supports CORS in Firefox 11 and later. This is expected to become standard soon.

Comment: It is not working. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:d2.example.com` is now showing in the response header. Yet `EventSource("http://d2.example.com/subscribe")` still produces the same error. I am using Chrome

Comment: 1) CORS + EventSource is a part of standart now; 2) CORS + EventSource is supported in FF 11+, Opera 12+, and will be in Chrome 25; 3) you acn use polyfill with CORS support for EventSource

Comment: Do you have a source for that?